# .Net Regex match only if input ends or with Newline/Whitespace

Tags: .net, regex

I have a .Net regex that works almost as expected (should match the value after a particular identifier key followed by an optional set of whitespace separated values inside brackets, see http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/113), however it matches a bit too loosely.

Basically it should only match if the match and optional () is either followed by the input's end, one or more whitespaces or newline(s).

The Regex used is:

```
^Identifier ([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(?:\(([^)(]*)\))?
```

And Sample(s) are:

```
Identifier abc sdfadf << should match 'abc'
Identifier a_123bc(def) << should match 'a_123bc' and 'def'

Identifier abcdef~ << does match but should NOT match because 'abcdef' is not followed by either line end, whitespace(s) or newline(s)
```

Does anyone know how to do this properly for aforementioned example?

Comment: You should really put the regex in the question and show why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the positive lookahead (for more details see for example this [article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)).  For example, if we add `(?=\s|$)` at the end of your regex, it will match only strings followed by a whitespace or the end of string but without matching this whitespace:

```
^Identifier ([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(?:\(([^)(]*)\))?(?=\s|$)
```

Comment: Thanks Michal, however it does not match (even though it should) if the string ends right after the last character.. if it is followed by a whitespaces/newline it does: http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/115

Answer (score 0):

```
^Identifier ([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(?:\(([^)(]*)\))?
```

The final ? is saying zero or one times, hence this will match anything that

```
^Identifier ([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)
```

would match.

it sounds like you want:

```
^Identifier ([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(?:\(([^)(]*)\))?(?=[\s$])
```

the final `(?=[\s$])` says end of line or whitespace as a positive lookahead

Comment: Hi tolanj - same here, it unfortunately does not match if the string ends directly like that: http://regex101.com/r/xV4eL5/1 .. if it is followed by a newline/whitespace.. it does